# accessibility support in jquery blockUI plugin

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, blockui, section508

I just wanted to know if blockUI provide any support for differently-abled / blind users ?
For example, when loading spinner is visible on screen, an announcement should be made for screen reader users eg. 'alert loading content' or something similar.

Please let me if same is already implemented or not?

```
<span aria-live="assertive" id="" class="sr-only" role="alert" style="display:none;">something is loading</span>
```

this span should be shown if loading spinner is visible

Answer (score 0):

Just using a demo, the plugin is not completely accessible. It would require extra work since the modal dialog does not properly handle all keyboard interaction at all. A user should be able to close the dialog with the Escape key. As well, clicking on the 'shade' area should close the dialog, and there's no close button for the pop-up. The user is forced into a choice.

Speaking to the animation specifically, I would suggest following the guidelines for timed media specific to video-only since there's an animation, and provide a clear explanation of the loader, but I would avoid using this method if at all possible. There are much clearer and cleaner methods for modals that are WCAG Compliant and still actively supported.

Time-Based Media: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#time-based-media